# gulp google-webfonts npm install

Tags: npm, gulp, bower

I would like to know if gulp google-webfonts should be installed using     `--save-dev` to be added to the devDependancies or would it be added using `-save` to bower.json dependancies.

I am using this in a project with Yeoman scaffolding using gulp and new to this.

Would appreciate some help thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-save`

- "dependencies": these packages are required by your application in production

`--save-dev`

- "devDependencies": these packages are only needed for development and testing

Since you will probably need google-webfonts in your production build I would go with `-save`.

[NPM Specifying Packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json#specifying-packages)

Comment: Yup I usually keep unit tests and gulp build stuff for devDepends, everything I need for production I just keep in dependencies. Can you mark this as the accepted answer? thanks!

Comment: after installing gulp google-webfonts it has been added to the bottom of my package.json file and listed as a dependancy. Would this still be treated the same and build the same as the dependancies listed in my Bower.json file?

Comment: If you ran ```bower install google-fonts -save``` it should. Running npm install or bower install is up to you, but usually people keep bower install for front end development and npm install for everything else.